# Using a for Loop to Concatenate

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to concatenate the values in 2 columns on separate dataframes along with the count #, and put the concatenated value in df1 column 'List'.

Currently, nothing is populating under column 'List'.   Any help is appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()   

df['Camp'] = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC']
df['Impr'] = [100, 600, 200]
df['Bid'] = [3, 5, 7]

df1 = pd.DataFrame() 
df1['Camp'] = ['XXX', 'YYY', 'ZZZ']
df1['Impr'] = [200, 300, 100]

df1.List = df.Camp + df1.Camp

print(df)

      Camp  Impr  Bid
    0  AAA   100    3
    1  BBB   600    5
    2  CCC   200    7

print(df1)

      Camp  Impr List
    0  XXX   200     
    1  YYY   300     
    2  ZZZ   100
```

Comment: There's a lot going wrong here. I think you would do well to revisit pandas basics. Read the user guide, do a kaggle course etc.

Comment: the reason you arent getting anything is here `df1.List == df.Camp + df1.Camp + x` notice you have a `==` equality test instead of a `=` assignment

Answer (score 0):

I think, if you are trying to add two columns from two different data frames then there is no need of loop and using == returns bool values

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()   

df['Camp'] = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC']
df['Impr'] = [100, 600, 200]
df['Bid'] = [3, 5, 7]

df1 = pd.DataFrame() 
df1['Camp'] = ['XXX', 'YYY', 'ZZZ']
df1['Impr'] = [200, 300, 100]
df1['List'] = ["","",""]

df1.List = df.Camp + df1.Camp

  Camp  Impr    List
0  XXX   200  AAAXXX
1  YYY   300  BBBYYY
2  ZZZ   100  CCCZZZ
```